# Access remotely magento /media/ folder?

Tags: php, magento, server, magento-1.9

x.com and y.com are on separate servers.

y.com is a copy of x.com. (i use it for testing)

Because /media/ folder on x.com is more that 27 GB how can i simply access that folder from y.com given the fact that is very hard and time consuming to download and upload this folder !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH for connect `y.com` to `x.com`

**Syntax**

`ssh username@192.168.11.25`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the media path in admin under `system->configuration->web->Base Media URL`. You can change the default value of this:

[image]

with

> x.com/media/